# Is it necessary to free ptr after invoke 'glGetString'

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm learning Android OpenGL. There is an official demo and code segment:
[gl_code.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/froyo-release/samples/hello-gl2/jni/gl_code.cpp)

```
static void printGLString(const char* name, GLenum glName) {
    const char* v = (const char*) glGetString(glName);
    LOGI("GL %s = %s\n", name, v); // print log : GL vendor=ARM

    // free((void*)v);   // my question ???
}

// invoke 
printGLString("vendor", GL_VENDOR);
```

This official demo *does not* invoke `free`.
Is it necessary to free `const char* v` after invoking `glGetString`?

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetString.xml):

> glGetString returns a pointer to a static string describing some aspect of the current GL connection. name can be one of the following: [...]

The string is managed by the library and because it is a static string you must not `free` it.